# Finding Local Maximum Of Functions

Tags: derivatives

If $h=fg$ be the product of two differentiable functions $f$ and $g$ If $f$ and $g$ are positive with local maxima at $x=a$and if $f'$ and $g'$ change sign at $x=a$, does $h$ have a local maximum at $x=a$

Comment: $$h'=f'g+fg'$$?

Answer (score 0):

It is true also if $f$ and $g$ are not differentiable. Infact if they are positive and $x=a$ is a local point of maximum for $f$ and $g$ then there exists two open set $A$ and $B$ of the point $a$ such that

$0\leq f(x)\leq f(a)$ for each $x\in A$

$0\leq g(x)\leq g(a)$ for each $x\in B$

then $A\cap B$ is an open neighborhood of $a$ and you have that

$fg(x)=f(x)g(x)\leq f(a)g(a)$ for each $x\in A\cap B$

so $a$ is a local maximum for $fg$